# Detect if touch coords are inside the coords of clickeable areas over a custom view

Tags: android, android-view, touch-event

I'm trying to make a custom view with clickeable areas for my app. Those areas are relative to the image pixel coords that will fill that view. I've placed those images at drawable-nodpi to avoid system scaling.

My custom view takes one of those images, resizes it keeping the aspect ratio to fit its parent and then resizes the view to the size of the resulting image. So at this point I have a view that maintains the ratio of the source, so the resulting view click (onTouch event.getX and event.getY) coordinates are relative to the original image pixel coords.

From the other hand I have all the coordinates of the shapes that define the clickeable areas in a xml file wich I load when my activity starts. Those areas are defined by a type: circle or rect.

circle: center x-y and radius in px according to the original image

rect: center x-y, width and height in px according to the original image

Now I need to detect if my touch x-y is inside of the coordinates of any of those areas, but keeping in mind the scaling that my original image suffered.

How could I detect the "collitions" between my touch coordinates and the clickeable areas coords? I mean how do I calculate that even without resizing my original image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing

```
for(i=0;i<level.getDiffs();i++){
            DifferencesData diff = level.getDifference(i);

            if(!diff.getFinded()){
                x = diff.getX();
                y = diff.getY();

                if(diff.getType() == 0){
                    double d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - event.getX(),2) + Math.pow(y - event.getY(),2));

                    if(d <= diff.getRadius()){
                        hit = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }else{
                    double dx = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - event.getX(),2));
                    double dy = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y - event.getY(),2));

                    if(dx <= (diff.getWidth() / 2) && dy <= (diff.getHeight() / 2)){
                        hit = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

First I scaled the original coordinates by the same scale that my image was scaled by. Then, inside an OnTouchListener I calculated the distance of my touch to the ratio of the circle, or to the half width and half height of my rectangles.

Thank you Daniel for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have made a View like this myself,

i added objects containing an image and x/y coords.

Now u need to have a list of those Objects, and in case you get an ontouchEvent, you iterate over that list do something like objectHit()

```
public boolean objectHit(int x, int y){
   int touchdistance = Math.sqrt((double)(this.getX()-x)*(double)(this.getX()-x)) + ((double)(this.getY()-y)*(double)(this.getY()-y));
   return touchdistance <= this.getTouchableArea();
}
```

And you implement getTouchableArea for the Object basicly the same way.

```
public double getTouchAbleArea() {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(getBitmap().getHeight(),2)+Math.pow(getBitmap().getWidth(),2))/2;   
}
```

So what you are doing with this code is, you determine if the touch is within the size of the Image representing the object.

Comment: You can get rid of the `sqrt()` calls, since you are only measuring relative distance.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you explain the math around it a little more? I'm having trouble following it. Is correct to say that the solution only works with rectangles?

Comment: actually im thinking of the Objects as Circles. ah important is, that you are calculating the touchDistance form the centered xCoordinate. or it might behave in a strange way :)